# Getting an error during a $POST request with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I am making a site with image manipulation, which saves an edited image on the server with the help of Imagick. However I get the current error during "$POST":

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://"mysite"/img_save"
```

and the "$POST" is not executed.
Looking at my error_log, it looks like this:

```
[28-Apr-2014 10:11:07 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file: /home2/label/public_html' in /home2/label/public_html/controller/img_save.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/label/public_html/controller/img_save.php(63): Imagick->readimage('/home2/label/pu...')
#1 /home2/label/public_html/index.php(37): require('/home2/label/pu...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /home2/label/public_html/controller/img_save.php on line 63
```

The piece of code that refers to the error is this:

```
$img_top = new Imagick();
$img_top->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_POST['main_view']); //Line 63
$img->compositeImage($img_top, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, -25, -75);
$img->writeImage('files/orders/' . $order_id . '.jpg');

echo json_encode(array('id'=>$order_id));
```

Can anyone tell me what is the nature of the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_POST['main_view']` is as you expect it? (Could be you need to put a slash there `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$_POST['main_view']`)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I've tried with the slash - same error. By "as you expect it" you ask if 'main_view' is located in document root? My "main_view" is located in /public_html/view/frontend/home.php. Maybe I should change the 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' to something else?

Comment: print it and see if it's how it should be, it's an easy check.Also, check file/folder permissions

Comment: @DamienPirsy Sorry for my delayed reply and the stupid question, but how do I print the result?

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_POST['main_view'];` ?